# The Schoenflies Theorem on two dimensional surfaces

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, surfaces

Let $S$ be a surface and $U$ an open connected subset of $S$. If the frontier of $U$ in $S$ is a two sided circle $C$, then the closure of $U$ in $S$ is a surface whose boundary is $C$. I would like to know if this result is known. Thanks

Comment: What does "two sided circle" mean?

Comment: By a two sided circle I mean an orientation preserving simple closed curve

Comment: I'm not sure what that means either. The only meaning of "orientation preserving" in this context I know if is for a map between oriented manifolds of the same dimension, so it's not clear to me what it would mean for a curve on a surface

Comment: A curve on a surface is said to be two-sided if it has a neighborhood homeomorphic to an annulus. Equivalently, there is a neighborhood basis of C consisting of open sets with U \ C two components.

Comment: Have you tried reading a textbook that describes the basics of surfaces and their submanifolds?   There are a lot of references that usually cover many other topics.  Guillemin and Pollack is one of my favourites.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is true. Let $S$ be a torus, and let $C$ be a non-separating simple closed curve in $S$. Let $U=S\setminus C$. Then $U$ is open and connected, and the frontier of $U$ is $C$. But the closure of $U$ is $S$ which has empty boundary.

Comment: Yes, one needs the additional assumption that C is separating (which implies that it is 2-sided).

Comment: It will also be necessary to assume that $S$ has empty boundary. If $\partial S\neq\emptyset$ and $\partial S$ is connected, then one can take $U$ as a regular open neighborhood of $\partial S$. Then the frontier $C$ is a connected 2-sided circle, but $\partial\overline{U}=C\cup\partial S$.

Comment: All observations were correct, thanks. $$ can not have boundary. Also, if $N$ is a neighbourhood of $C$ homeomorphic to an annulus, then one component of $N\setminus C$ is not contained in $U$.

Comment: @Mike Miller  I was just wandering if there were a version of Schoenflies Theorem that holds for two sided simple closed curves $C$ that are connected components of the frontier of an open connected subset $U$ of $S$. If $N$ is an annular neighbourhood of $C$ then we need that one component of $N\setminus C$ is not contained in $U$. $S$ can be any boundaryless surface.

Comment: The correct statement is that if $C,D$ are separating curve in the interior of a compact connected surface $S$ (with or without boundary), then there is a homeomorphism $\varphi: S \to S$ with $\varphi(C) = D$ if and only if $S \setminus C$ and $S \setminus D$ are homeomorphic. This follows essentially from the classification of compact surfaces and what I have called to you before the "unique disc lemma" though some work needs to be done (take closure on each side, cap off boundaries, etc). As Ryan suggests above this is all much much easier if you deal with smooth surfaces, curves, etc.